# Is there a better way to inspect property of swift object from a protocol than po each variable manually?

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, protocols

I have this code

```
public protocol UserItemModel {
    var identifier: String { get }
    var type: UserItemModelType { get }
    var isSelectable: Bool { get }
    var isActionable: Bool { get }
}

final class SampleItemModel: UserItemModel {
    let identifier: String
    var type: UserItemModelType
    var isSelectable: Bool
    var isActionable: Bool

    init(identifier: String = UUID().uuidString, 
         type: UserItemModelType = .user(SampleUserModel()), 
         isSelectable: Bool = false, 
         isActionable: Bool = true) {
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.type = type
        self.isSelectable = isSelectable
        self.isActionable = isActionable
    }
}
```

When I debug this with breakpoint the value show is this.

[image]

Always payload_xxx and the only way I can inspect the value is to po with the individual property manually. This is even worse when I debug `[UserItemModel]`.

Is there a way to make all the properties show in the variable panes directly? like in Objective-C.

Thanks.

Comment: Gah, this really irks me. The data you see in the left panel under `itemModel` is guts of a protocol witness, which is a fixed-sized container into which value types (structs, tuples, enums) are wrapped, so that they can be stored alongside other protocol witnesses (of values that can be of different types, thus different sizes and such). For example, this is used when storing an array by a protocol (like `[Any]`). This is an implementation detail of Swift, and it's infuriating that it leaks into public view in the debugger like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the global [`dump(_:name:indent:maxDepth:maxItems:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1539127-dump) function.

```
expr dump(itemModel)
```

Also, LLDB is highly scriptable via Python, so you can also look into that

Comment: This is probably better than po, but still not convenient enough. Because if the variable is a lot of including sub variables this show everything at once. I remember before we have something like expandable when click variable for objective-c on the variable pane.

Comment: @SaintTail Set `maxDepth` to 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe similar to the response that Alexander gave but there is also the `p` command

```
p itemModel
```

Gives less output than `dump(_:name:indent:maxDepth:maxItems:)` but is more descriptive than `po` command